# ORA-00905: missing keyword specification4

Tags: sql, oracle, join

For the query below

```
select gi.group_members as ID, em.EMP_NAME as NAME, em.EMAIL as EMAIL 
from groupinfo gi 
  join empmaster em
where gi.group_members= em.'3'|| emp_code || '0';
```

I am getting error

> ORA-00905: missing keyword
>   specification4

Comment: em.'3' does not look right. What do you want to do here?

Comment: in group_members has 8 digit no as 31111110.   and emp_code has 6 digit no as 111111, but i want it as 3111110 so i used .'3'|| emp_code || '0'

Comment: `em.'3'` does not make sense

Comment: You can not use that notation in oracle. try '3'|| emp_code || '0'  Skipping the em. part

Comment: Also use aliases everywhere  '3'|| em.emp_code || '0'

Comment: Are you trying to compare "gi"."group_members" againts 3rd column from "em"? That should be em.3 (not em.'3').

Comment: You are missing the `ON` condition for the `JOIN` operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a wrong notation for emp_code  is `'3' || em.emp_code || '0'` and not  `em.'3'......` (because there wrong refere to  a column named '3' in em .. table

```
    select gi.group_members as ID, em.EMP_NAME as NAME, em.EMAIL as EMAIL 
    from groupinfo gi 
    join empmaster em ON  gi.group_members= '3'||em.emp_code || '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this with an example and it works.

```
 create table a
    ( id number,
      name varchar2(12));


    create table b
    ( id number,
      name varchar2(12));

    insert into b
      values (1,'arc123123');


    insert into a
      values (1,'arc123');

      SELECT a.id, b.name 
      FROM a, b
      WHERE b.name= a.name||'123';
```